# user rights to add document in library SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, rights, spgroup

I want to check, if user can add document in document library then custom action is enabled. 
I used 
[this article](http://www.necronet.org/archive/2011/07/25/enable-or-disable-ribbon-custom-action-based-on-user-permissions.aspx).

And then I encountered the following problem:
I don't know how check user rights of adding for this library.

I try to use SPGroup of current web, but I need to know names of groups, and this names is not constant. 
I can get roles of current user, but how can get information about what this set of roles contain the role of type SPRoleType.Contributor?

I would be grateful for any attempt to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I found solution!

```
bool t = list.Permissions.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPRights.AddListItems)
```

Return `true` if user can add document to library!